# Windows in Parallels: Can a Windows virus destroy my Mac files?

Tags: macos, windows-8.1, virus, macbook-pro, dropbox

I've mac book pro with OS X 10.9.1

On this machine I've installed Windows 8.1 in Parallels.

If I get a virus on Windows can it destroy my files on my Mac?

For example I see that my Dropbox from my OSX is included in Windows, which means that at least my Dropbox files can be theoretically destroyed. How can I prevent that?

I'm new to OSX.

Comment: You can't?  The best way would be to avoid infecting the virtual machine with malicious files. Believe it or not the and mass difficult, is actually false, its pretty easy to keep a windows machine clean.

Comment: So a Windows virus can affect all my files, not only the Dropbox?

Comment: The virus within the virtual machine would effect the shared files.   It could encrypt them or make them completely useless.  Just don't get infected and/or don't share files between the virtual machine and the host.